# Deleting linked list in C

Tags: c, list, free

I am trying to create a function that deletes an entire list, but I keep getting an error.
Everything works excepting cleaner() function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int n;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node NOD;

NOD *create_first_node(int i)
{
    NOD *q;
    q=(NOD*)malloc(sizeof(NOD*));
    q->n=i;
    q->next=NULL;
    return q;
}

NOD * add_to(NOD *x)
{
    NOD *q;
    q=(NOD*)malloc(sizeof(NOD*));
    q->n=rand();
    x->next=q;
    q->next=NULL;
    return q;
}

void show_list(NOD *p)
{
    printf("root");
    while(p->next){
        printf(" -> %d",p->n);
        p=p->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}


void cleaner(NOD *p)
{
    NOD *r;
    while(p)
    {
        r=p;
        p=r->next;
        free(r);
        r=NULL;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int i;
    NOD *root,*c,*r;
    root=create_first_node(1);
    c=r=root;
    c=add_to(root);
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        r=c;
        c=add_to(r);
    }
    show_list(root);
    //cleaner(root);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

NetBeans:

Signal received: SIGTRAP (?) with sigcode ? (?)
From process: ?
For program list, pid -1

You may discard the signal or forward it and you may continue or pause the process
To control which signals are caught or ignored use Debug->Dbx Configure

---

Visual Studio:

Debug Error!

HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#57) at
0x00393230
CRC detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

(I get this error with #57,#58,...,#68 each time cleaner() is trying to free a list item)

Comment: The "heap corruption" is an immediate hint that you have made some kind of mistake with a pointer, btw. Walking off the end of an allocation, double free, following a un-intilized pointer, ... lots of choices, but all *pointer* related. In a case like this that might not seem very helpful, but it is worth remembering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`q=(NOD*)malloc(sizeof(NOD*));` should be `q=(NOD*)malloc(sizeof(NOD));`, I think.

You need to allocate enough memory for the whole Node, but you are only allocating enough for a pointer to it.

Answer (score 1):

I admit I have just skimmed your code, but when you create and add nodes, you do a

```
 q=(NOD*)malloc(sizeof(NOD*));
```

but you should actually do a

```
 q=(NOD*)malloc(sizeof(NOD));
```

Otherwise you will just allocate the space for a NOD* which is 4 or 8 bytes depending on your system (and assuming it is a common PC). But your NOD struct will have at least 8 or 16 bytes (again depending on your system and the size of your int's and assuming you are using common PC hardware).

So when you access the **n** member you are already on barely legal ground but when you later touch the **next** member, you are in the middle of undefined behaviour, and lucky you your software causes only a heap corruption...

Answer (score 0):

- `NULL` is not *necessarily* the same as 0. It *usually* is, but you "shouldn't" assume it will be. So, `while(p)` is dangerous … please use `while (NULL != p)` or `(p != NULL)` :-)
- When using `malloc`, you're allocating the size of a `NOD*`, a pointer; you meant to use `sizeof(NOD)`.
- Also, don't put a typecast `(NOD*)` on the return of `malloc`. (Google "malloc typecast" for a laundry list of reasons, but suffice to say, it's uneccessary and fairly likely to break your code and hide bugs later.)
- The `r = NULL` is superfluous, but it's a good habit to get into, to clear the pointer after `free()`, so that's not bad :-)

Comment: I'm not sure I agree entirely with the first point. NULL is defined in <stddef.h>. Any C programmer who redefines it as anything other than 0 should be removed from the building. And `while (p)` is guaranteed to be false when `p` is a Null Pointer.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/459743/10396

Comment: Wasn't aware of the special-case for while(p). As for "defined in `stddef.h` — yes, it's defined there, but it's implementation-specific: it may be defined by a particular OS/CPU combination to be anything; e.g. `0xffff` isn't entirely rare on embedded systems with 16-bit memory addressing; `-1` is actually used on many systems. The `NULL == 0` concept is jokingly referred to as, "All the world's a VAX" … it happens to often be true on Intel + (Linux, Windows, MacOS), but still not a great idea to "count on it"…