# Can strncpy return 0?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

The man page of `strncpy` states:

> char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);
>
> The  strcpy()  and  strncpy() functions return a pointer to the destination string dest.

Is it possible that `strncpy(buff, "something", 9) == 0` be true if `char buff[100]`?

**UPDATE**

I also consider it as not very probable but it's part of a program that I should make to bufferoverflow and this condition stays on my way to achieve this.

Comment: Why is that supposed to return 0?

Comment: The only case when it can return NULL (I guess) would be `strncpy(NULL, "something", 0)`...

Comment: Since it returns the destination string, and when compared with `0`, a pointer is checked for being `NULL`, and `NULL` is not a valid memory location to copy to, hence no, this function cannot legally return a pointer that compares equal to 0.

Comment: But when you pass `NULL` pointer the function does not return 0. *"If strDest or strSource is a NULL pointer, or if count is less than or equal to zero, the invalid parameter handler is invoked, as described in Parameter Validation. If execution is allowed to continue, these functions return -1 and set errno to EINVAL"* (MSVC).

Comment: @WeatherVane also, cppreference [says](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy): "The behavior is undefined if either dest or src is not a pointer to a character array." – I couldn't find this clause in my copy of the C99 standard, but I've also read somewhere that when "a pointer to…" is required, and the standard does not explicitly say that the supplied pointer may be `NULL` in some circumstances, then it should not be `NULL`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: That may be true for MSVC, but I don't believe it's in any sort of C standard...

Comment: If you want to use some buffer overflow/stack smashing then sure, you can get it to return anything you want. But that's implementation dependent, and totally changes this question. I might suggest opening a new question if that's what you want to ask.

Comment: @Cornstalks You're right, I just wanted some opinions if it's possible in normal conditions.

Comment: @Zozo - in *normal* conditions?  No, it won't happen.  But if your process does `mmap()` with `MAP_FIXED`, and somehow `NULL` gets passed to `mmap` as the first parameter, you will find that `NULL` references valid memory.  There are probably other memory-management functions that can do the same (although `shmat()` seems immune to this type of abuse because of the way it's specified.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/shmat.html)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: pointing out that there are (abnormal) ways to get it to return null is neat, but spamming it across all the answers is just going to cause confusion to readers, given the fact that no, it can't return null under normal circumstances.

Comment: @Zozo: If your interest is in normal conditions, then I might suggest you remove your **UPDATE**, as that's modifying the question to include abnormal conditions.

Comment: @Cornstalks As I pointed out in response to other (now deleted and cleaned) comments, the preconditions are not *that* hard to cause to happen inadvertently.  Answers that unequivocally state **NO** are simply incorrect.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: No, they, aren't incorrect. mmaping null as a writable fixed region of memory and then passing it to strcpy is not normal (yes, it can be useful, but no, it's not normal). I'm pretty sure the OP means well-defined/well-behaved execution when referring to "normal conditions." Answers that state "no" don't authoritatively override the meaning of undefined behavior, and as such, if your program has undefined behavior, then yeah, sure, expect anything. But nasal demons aren't normal (or at the very least, shouldn't be).

Comment: @Cornstalks - They **are** incorrect.  I've demonstrated that.  What Zozo does with the information I've provided is up to him - only he really knows the entire context of his question.  Continually trying to minimize the information I've posted is imposing your beliefs on his context.

Comment: "They are incorrect. I've demonstrated that." -- You have done no such thing. The question is about `char buff[100]; strncpy(buff, "something", 9)` ... that *cannot* return NULL because `buff` *cannot* be NULL.

Comment: OP is asking the wrong question. The bug most likely has to do with the fact that `strncpy` doesn't NUL-terminate the destination.

Comment: @AlexLop. C11 states: " Where an argument declared as `size_t n` specifies the length of the array for a
function, `n` can have the value zero on a call to that function. Unless explicitly stated
otherwise in the description of a particular function in this subclause, pointer arguments
on such a call shall still have valid values, as described in 7.1.4."

Answer (score 5):

**No**.

Judging from the facts that

1. [The null pointer constant `NULL`'s value equals `0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894013/is-null-always-zero-in-c)
2. A `NULL` pointer shall not point to a valid object. From the C11 standard, §6.3.2.3:

   > [...] a null pointer [,] is guaranteed to compare
   >   unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

and that the corresponding man page does not mention the possibility of `dest == NULL`,

it is **not** allowed to.

Comment: It *can* return `NULL` if a valid character array exists at an address that corresponds to the value of `NULL`.  Pass `NULL` to `mmap()` with `MAP_FIXED` set and it will likely happily map away at a virtual address of zero.

Answer (score 4):

Think about it. What does the man page say? It says it returns `dest`. Therefore, if `dest` is not `NULL`, then the return value will not be `NULL`.

Since `buff` will never be `NULL` (assuming it's `char buff[100]`), then you can say with certainty that no, it will never return `NULL`.

If it does, it's got a bug.

Comment: `mmap()` a writeable page at address 0 on a system that uses zero for a `NULL`.  Your system will probably allow that.  Then call `strcpy( NULL, s );`, and it will return `NULL`.  UB is UB - any result can happen, and it's not a bug if it does.

Comment: Actually, I have to find the bug in the given program and to make a bufferoverflow.

Comment: Well yeah, sure, if you want to play with undefined behavior, then anything can happen. But I think that's out of the scope of the question (at least the original question). The original question had no mention of undefined behavior, and clearly mentioned the pointer passed to the function wasn't `NULL` (and didn't involve any buffer overflows).

Comment: @Zozo - *Actually, I have to find the bug in the given program and to make a bufferoverflow.*  Don't go about searching for memory errors by manually hunting for them - use a tool like `valgrind`.  Looking for memory errors manually is unlikely to work - if it were easy, the original code wouldn't have the error.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: FYI, I state if `dest` is not `NULL`, then the return value will not be `NULL`. I never said anything about it not returning `NULL` if `dest` is `NULL` itself.

Comment: "Don't go about searching for memory errors by manually hunting for them - use a tool like valgrind. Looking for memory errors manually is unlikely to work - if it were easy, the original code wouldn't have the error." -- This is completely clueless. The OP has an exploitable program and is tasked with figuring out the exploit. valgrind is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion if the executed code doesn't contain any undefined behavior, the given code cannot return `NULL`.

The only case when it can return `NULL` is if the destination is `NULL`. In such case (**most likely**) the execution will segfault unless the number of copied characters is 0.

In the given example:

```
strncpy(buff, "something", 9)
```

Neither the destination can be `NULL` ( since it is `char buff[100]`), nor number of copied characters can be 0 since it is given as 9.

Answer (score 1):

According to the ISO/IEC 9899:2011 standard *§7.24.2.4/c4 The `strncpy`: function*

> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> 1   #include <string.h>
>     char *strncpy(char * restrict s1,
>     const char * restrict s2,
>     size_t n);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> 2 The `strncpy` function copies not more than `n` characters (characters that > follow a null character are not copied) from the array pointed to by `s2` to 
>   the array pointed to by
>
> 3 If the array pointed to by `s2` is a string that is shorter than n characters, > null characters are appended to the copy in the array pointed to by `s1`, until 
>   n characters in all have been written.
>
> **Returns**
>
> 4 **The `strncpy` function returns the value of s1.**
>   `s1`. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is 
>   undefined.

As such, the only way for `strncpy` to return `0` (i.e., `NULL`) with out causing undefined behaviour is if `s1` is `NULL` and `n` is zero.

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e6d46ffafab01f6)

Answer (score 0):

Yes `strncpy()` can return `NULL`.  Just `mmap` a writeable page at address zero on a system that defines `NULL` as a pointer with zero as its numeric value:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    char *p;
    char *buf = mmap( ( void * ) 0, 4096,
        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_FIXED | MAP_ANON, -1, 0 );
    p = strncpy( buf, "string", strlen( "string" ) );
    printf( "p: %p\n", p );
    printf( "NULL: %p\n", NULL );
    return( 0 );
}
```

Yes, this is intentionally violating the C standard requirement that `NULL` must not point to a valid object, so it's undefined behavior.

But it **CAN** happen.

Comment: Did you actually *try* that code? While it is true that Linux will allow you to mmap page 0 using `MAP_FIXED`, only the privileged user has permissions to do so. Running your code as a normal user will segfault because the mmap returns (void*)(-1) with errno set to EPERM. Also, `#include <strings.h>` is wrong (and will result in `strncpy` not being declared), and if you compile in a strict environment (eg `-std=c11`), then you need `#define _BSD_SOURCE` (or `_GNU_SOURCE`) in order for `MAP_ANON` to be defined. See http://ideone.com/hM6MkH

Comment: @rici The POSIX **standard** for `mmap()` (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html) lists no such restrictions. The world extends beyond Linux.

Comment: The POSIX **standard** doesn't include MAP_ANON, which is why you need a non-standard feature-test macro to get it defined.