# Is C NULL equal to C++11 nullptr

Tags: c, c++11, null, interop

I like to use `nullptr` instead of NULL. Now I call a C function (from `libjansson` in this case).

`NULL` in C is implementation [defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/NULL).

For `nullptr` I found that "A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero".

So the safest thing to do:

```
auto string_obj=json_object_get(m_handle,name);
if(string_obj!=NULL)
    {
    auto string=json_string_value(string_obj);
    if(string!=NULL)
        {return string;}
    }
return nullptr;
```

Do I really need that or can I do it simpler:

```
auto string_obj=json_object_get(m_handle,name);
if(string_obj!=nullptr)
    {
    return json_string_value(string_obj); //Assume there is no difference between C NULL and C++11 nullptr
    }
return nullptr;
```

Comment: Chose the language. The language then tells you what to use. You cannot mix-n-match

Comment: @EdHeal: This is an interoperability question.

Comment: For C functions that you are calling from  C++ you use NULL in there arguments as appropriate. Otherwise use nullptr. If moving from C++ to C do `v == nullptr ? NULL : v` and vice versa

Comment: @EdHeal Why would you do that?  Assigning `nullptr` to a pointer in C++ does the same thing as assigning `NULL` (or heck `0`) does as far as C++ is concerned: `X* ptr = NULL;`, `X* ptr=nullptr;` and `X* ptr=0;` *do the same thing in C++*.  Similarly, `ptr == NULL` and `ptr == nullptr` and `ptr==0` and `!ptr` are all guaranteed to return the same value in C++ code.

Comment: I thought that NULL does not have to be zero. Just needs to compare to zero. Therefore nullptr may not equal NULL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894013/is-null-always-zero-in-c

Comment: `int c = NULL;`  will compile.  `int c = nullptr;` will not.  `nullptr` was designed so that it cannot be assigned to an `int`.  There is a difference.

Comment: `nullptr` is not exactly the same as the "a nullpointer constant" that you "found somewhere, but I don't tell you where" (it's the C++ standard by the way, and an old version of that.)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

In C++11 and beyond, a pointer that is `==NULL` will also `==nullptr` and vice versa.

Uses of `NULL` other than comparing with a pointer (like using it to represent the nul byte at the end of a string) won't work with `nullptr`.

In some cases, `NULL` is `#define NULL 0`, as the integer constant `0` is special-cased in C and C++ when you compare it with pointers.  This non-type type information causes some problems in both C and C++, so in C++ they decided to create a special type and value that does the same thing in the "proper" use cases, and reliably fails to compile in most of the "improper" use cases.

Insofar as your C++ implementation is compatible with the C implementation you are interoping with (very rare for this not to be true), everything should work.

---

To be very clear, if `ptr` is any kind of pointer, then the following expressions are equivalent in C++:

```
ptr == nullptr
ptr == NULL
ptr == 0
!ptr
```

As are the following:

```
ptr = nullptr
ptr = NULL
ptr = 0
```

and if `X` is some type, so are the following statements:

```
X* ptr = nullptr;
X* ptr = NULL;
X* ptr = 0;
```

`nullptr` differs when you pass it to a template function that deduces type (`NULL` or `0` become an `int` unless passed to an argument expecting a pointer, while `nullptr` remains a `nullptr_t`), and when used in some contexts where `nullptr` won't compile (like `char c = NULL;`) (note, not `char* c=NULL;`)

Finally, literally:

```
NULL == nullptr
```

is true.

The `NULL` constant gets promoted to a pointer type, and as a pointer it is a null pointer, which then compares equal to `nullptr`.

---

Despite all this, it isn't always true that:

```
 foo(NULL)
```

and

```
 foo(nullptr)
```

do the same thing.

```
void bar(int) { std::cout << "int\n"; }
void bar(void*) { std::cout << "void*\n"; }
template<class T>
void foo(T t) { bar(t); }
foo(NULL);
foo(nullptr);
```

[this prints `int` for `NULL` and `void*` for `nullptr`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5a2ad1355cfd101).

Comment: great and extensive answer