# Loading a trie data structure in C- pset5 cs50

Tags: c, load, trie, cs50

I am having trouble loading data into my trie structure. I keep getting a sgemenation fault. Does this have to do with my malloc? Anyone see any issues?

Thanks

```
/**
 * dictionary.c
 *
 * Computer Science 50
 * Problem Set 5
 *
 * Implements a dictionary's functionality.
 */

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dictionary.h"


#define ASCII_OFFSET 97;

/** Node of the data structure used to store the dictionary key words
 * Data Structures Type is Tries
 * Includes a bool to indicate if the current node is the end of a word
 * A pointer to the nodes child node
 */
typedef struct node
{
    bool is_word;
    struct node* children[27];
}
node;
node* rootNode;
node* nextNode;

//Variable to track the size of the dictinoary
int wordCount = 0;

/**
 * Returns true if word is in dictionary else false.
 */

bool check(const char* word)
{
    //Get words length
    int wordLength = strlen(word);

    for(int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++)
    {
        //taking the character we need to check
        int charToCheck = tolower(word[i]) - ASCII_OFFSET;

        //Checking to see if the char exists in the data strucutre, Trie;
        if(nextNode->children[charToCheck] == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        //Advance the next node down the trie
        nextNode = nextNode->children[charToCheck];
    }

    nextNode = rootNode;
    //Return what is_word return
    return nextNode->is_word;
}

/**
 * Loads dictionary into memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
 */

bool load(const char* dictionary)
{
    //Open dict.. file to read 
    FILE* file = fopen(dictionary,"r");

    //Check if the dict.. exsists!
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Creating the first node in our data strucutre
    rootNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    nextNode = rootNode;

    //Get character to store
    int character = fgetc(file) - ASCII_OFFSET;

    //Go through the dict... file 
    while(character != EOF)
    {
        //Go through each word in the file
        while(character != '\n')
        {
            //Add into our data structure
            if(nextNode->children[character] == NULL)
            {
                //Create memory inorder to insert the next node
                nextNode->children[character] = malloc(sizeof(node));
                nextNode = nextNode->children[character];
            }else {
                nextNode = nextNode->children[character];
            }

            //advance character to next
            character = fgetc(file) - ASCII_OFFSET;
        }

        //advance character to next word
        character = fgetc(file) - ASCII_OFFSET;

        //Set the last node loaded to is_word to track the end of each word
        nextNode->is_word = true;
        wordCount++;
        nextNode = rootNode;
    }


    fclose(file);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded.
 */

unsigned int size(void)
{
    return wordCount;
}

/**
 * Unloads dictionary from memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
 */

bool unload(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if(nextNode->children[i] != NULL)
        {
            nextNode = nextNode->children[i];
            unload();
        }
    }

    free(nextNode);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Congratulations, you've pasted an assignment into the internet. What was your question?

Comment: Sorry, I was having trouble loading my trie, kept getting a segmentation error.

Comment: What is a "trie"? (Ssh, don't help the OP!)

Comment: A [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is an interesting type of search tree. And, menan - if you have a segmentation error, you should either have a core dump you can load in a debugger, or you can just run the program in your debugger and see it stop at the point when the error occurs. Typically segv means you have a NULL pointer, or an uninitialized pointer, or some other horrible thing.

Comment: The semicolon in `#define ASCII_OFFSET 97;` is not wanted.  But if the code compiles with it present, are you actually using `ASCII_OFFSET` at all? (Answer: yes, it is used, at least twice, but at the end of an expression so the extra semi-colon is just an empty statement.)  Would it be clearer to use `#define ASCII_OFFSET 'a'`?

Comment: You don't properly initialize the allocated trie structure element.  You need to make sure all those pointers are nulled.

Comment: How do I NULL these pointers, I have used malloc, and callo?

Comment: @menan Use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't check that a char is in range before using it as index in the array. Any character outside the range a-z will cause buffer overflow.
2. You compare the character to known character constants *after* you have subtracted 97 from it.
3. You need to initialize the memory returned from malloc by assigning `NULL` to all array elements and set `is_word` to false.

Just took a short glance at the code, so I may have missed additional bugs.

Comment: You should also use calloc instead of malloc because you check for NULL but malloc doesn't give you a defined memory value.

Comment: @maxbit89 You raise a valid point. I don't think  `NULL` is required to be `0` by the standard (even though "all" implementations seem to have it as `0`), so I've chosen to recommend explicitly setting the pointers to `NULL` instead.

Comment: Yes perse it is not defined in Standard but it is well used ^^. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894013/is-null-always-zero-in-c