# Difference between below two c statements

Tags: c, static, initialization, extern

Can anyone please let me know the difference between below two c statements in terms of initialization, scope of `table` and any other.

NOTE:Both are **global variables**.

```
unsigned int *table[100] = {NULL};

static unsigned int *table[100] = {NULL};
```

Comment: Please be aware that `... = {NULL}`  *only initialises the array's 1st element* to `NULL`. *All other elements get initialised to `0`, Both not necessarily need to be the same depending on the C implementation in use.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch: A duplicate by the title, but not by the content, I feel.

Comment: Referring my previous comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9894013/694576

Answer (score 1):

1. `table` is an array of pointers of type `unsingned int` in both the declarations.
2. The difference is with `static` the visibility of the array is restricted only to the file in which you are declaring this array.

The link will help

[What does "static" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-a-c-program)

Answer (score 0):

Similarity:

1. Both are array of 100 integer pointers.
2. Even if you don't initialize, both will be initialized to NULL as
   they are declared global.
3. Both will be stored into Data section.

Difference:

1. **Scope**: First one will have global scope which will be accessed
   anywhere from your program. Second one will have file scope means
   you can not access those pointers form other file.

**Note that if you declared both in the same file then static declaration will get highest preference. i.e. Assigning any value to table pointer will get static initialization.**

Comment: Please see my comment on the OP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39653161/difference-between-below-two-c-statements#comment66609677_39653161

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int *table[100] = {NULL};
```

`table` is an array of pointer to `unsingned int` and initialize  entire array elements to `NULL`.

```
static unsigned int *table[100] = {NULL};//declared as static means  initialized only once
```

`table` is an array of pointer to `static unsingned int` and initialize  entire array elements to `NULL`.

Comment: Please see my comment on the OP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39653161/difference-between-below-two-c-statements#comment66609677_39653161

Comment: @alk sir but remaining elements are implicitly NULL. am I right or wrong?

Comment: Not necessarily. Please have a look at link I just added as (another) comment to the OP.