# In this program please explain the output

Tags: c, pointers, null

```
void main()
{
    int a=5,*p,*c=NULL;
    printf("p=%u",p);    //OUTPUT p=3839036080
    printf("\nc=%u",c);  //OUTPUT c=0

}
```

Here we haven't assigned any address to `p` then why is it even printing anything? And `c` is assigned `NULL` so this means it stores the value as `0`?

Comment: Don't uninitialised variables have some value even though those are garbage values. Pointer is also a variable: a named location in memory.

Comment: *Here we haven't assigned any address to p then why is it even printing anything* - what would you expect it to do?

Comment: [Is NULL always zero in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9894013/669576)

Comment: [What happens to a declared, uninitialized variable in C? Does it have a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1597405/669576)

Comment: memory has one of two states .. 0 or 1. There is no third "nothing" value. If you have some memory that you haven't assigned anything to (`p`) then _something_ is still there.

Comment: You should learn to search for this stuff on your own.

Answer (score 0):

> Here we haven't assigned any address to p then why is it even printing anything?

You called `printf()`, so it has to print *something*. The variable is uninitialized, so it prints whatever happened to be in the memory used to hold the variable.

> And c is assigned NULL so this means it stores the value as 0?

Yes, `NULL` is a macro that expands to either `0`, `(char *)0`, or something equivalent.