# How can C compiler understand false as false and true as true when using enum?

Tags: c, boolean

How can the C compiler understand `isOn` as false if the return value of the variable is `0`?

```
enum bool { false, true };

typedef enum bool boolean;

int main()
{
    boolean isOn = false;
    printf("%d\n", isOn);
    if(!isOn)
        printf("IS FALSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Do C understand `0` as null and all other numbers as non-null?

Comment: `0` evaluates to false. All others evaluate to true.

Comment: Don't use homebrew boolean type, use `bool` from `stdbool.h`

Comment: What do you mean with null and non-null? `false` and `true` or `null` as in `null` pointer? The former has nothing to do with the latter.

Comment: Long time a go someone have said to me 0 in C is considered `null` and `null` could be considered `false` in some occasions.

Comment: @RodrigoXavier -- the null pointer macro in C is `NULL` , not `null`. There are null pointers, and `NULL`: with `int *x = NULL;` you have `x`, a null pointer which is guaranteed to compare equal to the null pointer macro `NULL`. It is true that null pointers evaluate to false in conditional expressions; `NULL` is typically (always?) defined as `(void *) 0`, i.e., the integer constant `0` cast to a `void` pointer.

Comment: See this question for further information on null-pointer and NULL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894013/is-null-always-zero-in-c

Answer (score 1):

In C the integer value 0 is considered false when used in a boolean context, while any non-zero value is considered true in a boolean context.

The values of an `enum` start at 0 and increase if not specifically set, so for the enum you've created, `false` has a value of 0 while `true` has a value of 1.

In the statement `if (!isOn)`, the `!` operator changes the boolean value of the given expression, with `!0` being 1 and any other value given being `0`.  Since `isOn` has the value 0, `!isOn` has the value 1, so the `if` statement is true and `"IS FALSE"` is printed.

Answer (score -1):

By default, C compiler has no `bool` type (and `true`/`false` definitions). `bool` type is implemented in system header `stdbool.h`, you should include it at first.

As I know, gcc compiler implements `true` and `false` as `0` and `1` defines, Microsoft MSVC (Microsoft Visual Studio) as `0` and `204`.

And yes, 0 in C is false and other value is true

Comment: Are you saying that `printf("%d", true)` in MSVC will print `204` ? I find it hard to believe.

Comment: I'm see that in debugger. I'm using MSVC in Visual Studio 2017.5.6.
And I see true(204) near bool