# compiler allows 'char * k= false'? Why?

Tags: c++

I found strange from my point of view compiler behavior, It allows assign  Boolean value to `* char`.

```
char * k= false;
```

Why? But after assignment * char is still not initialized. Why compilers doesn't allows assign `int` value?

Comment: That makes `k` a NULL pointer just like `char * k = 0`.

Comment: It is an implicit conversion from `bool` to `char *`. However, this works only for constant expressions that convert to (int) 0, which is a special initializer for pointers. Would be interesting if someone quoted the respective rule from the standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be implicitly converting the boolean value `false` to an integer with value zero and as such declaring a NULL pointer. It is effectively no different from

```
char* k = 0;
```

which is valid syntax

Answer (score 2):

C++03 Standard, #4.10:

> A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19)
>   rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero.

5.19:

> An integral constant-expression can involve only literals (2.13),
>   enumerators, const variables or static data members of integral or
>   enumeration types initialized with constant expressions (8.5),
>   non-type tem- plate parameters of integral or enumeration types, and
>   sizeof expressions.

`false` is a boolean literal, therefore it falls into the category of a constant expression, so it can qualify as a null pointer constant.

Comment: And `bool` is an integral type (3.9.1/7).

Answer (score 0):

`false` and `true` are shortcuts for `0` and `1`. For pointer you use `NULL` which `define NULL 0`. So it correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler allows it because in C++ `false` is the same as `0` and `NULL`.

Personally, at least for assignments, I find it easier to understand and more correct to use `NULL` to indicate a null pointer.

Btw, before C++, on some systems `NULL` was actually a macro defined as `(void*)0xffff`; some background on that can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/459805/1338292).

Comment: I would need to verify that in the standard, but in C++, NULL is 0. Looking at B. Stroustrup page, I have the confirmation from C++'s initial creator itself: http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null

Comment: @paercebal I was furiously looking to find where I remembered it from, so I've rephrased my answer in the meantime :)

Comment: FWIW, [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_datatype) "C++ has a separate Boolean data type ('bool'), but with automatic conversions from scalar and pointer values that are very similar to those of C". Don't have the standard at hand right now.

Comment: A precision: From section 4.10 of the standard (N3337), we have: `A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue **of integer type that evaluates to zero** or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t`. This means that no matter the system, in C++, NULL will always be an integer type that will evaluate to zero.

Comment: @paercebal I must admit that I've never read the C++ standard, but it's good that this was standardized :) I found my source btw, I've added a link to another answer.

Comment: @Jack : You give me too much credit. I knew about the integer zero thing from Stroustrup's web page. But I didn't read the C++ standard (but I still plan to...). Just made a search for NULL in the N3337 document (google for it), and read each occurrence until I found what I needed... ^_^ ...