# Under Xcode 6.3, NULL C++ reference address evaluates as non-zero

Tags: c++, xcode, pointers, memory-alignment, type-safety

Similar to this question:
[XCode 6.3 Warning : Comparison of address of 'myObject' not equal to null pointer is always true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560015/xcode-6-3-warning-comparison-of-address-of-myobject-not-equal-to-null-pointe)

with C++, I found that previously working code for evaluating null pointers stopped working:

```
struct AStruct
{
    int x, y;
    char *name;
};

AStruct& GetStruct()
{
   return *(AStruct*)0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    AStruct& mys = GetStruct();

    if ( ! &mys) {
        printf("null pointer \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("NOT a null pointer\n");
    }

    return 0
}
```

This always prints out 
`NOT a null pointer`

I've tried other ways of pointer-to-reference checking:

`if ( &mys == NULL)`

`if ( &mys == nullptr )`

None of these worked.

Then I noticed the warning:

```
Reference cannot be bound to dereferenced null pointer in well-defined C++ code; comparison may be assumed to always evaluate to false
```

But there are no suggested fixes.

What is the canonical way of checking null pointers these days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking against a pointer, you are checking against a reference.

References are not supposed to be `nullptr` since they must refer to an existing value. Indeed what you are doing `*(AStruct*)0` is not well defined since a reference shouldn't be able to generate undefined behaviour through "dereferencing it" but in this way you could trigger the problem.

If client code has a `AStruct&` then it can be sure that the reference points to something, you are breaking this condition.

If you need to work with references that can be null use a pointer, eg

```
AStruct* GetStruct()
{
  return nullptr;
}

if (!GetStruct())
{
  ...
```

The fact that the code worked in a previous version of Xcode is a symptom of the fact that this is not well-defined code.

Comment: Thank you. The "Not well-defined code" was rather shocking. I tried to cast `mys` to `int` or `intptr_t` and all that. The value itself is zero too. It even worked when turning off optimization. But with optimization it stops working. Anyways, the original code was not good practice I know. But the values I saw was rather counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a pointer there; `mys` is a reference. Then when you check the value of `&mys`, you are checking the address of the reference.

Comment: References don't have addresses, there is no guarantee that they have one since they could have no storage at all. Asking for the address of a reference yields the address of the referenced object.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jack. I think "Asking for the address of a reference yields the address of the referenced object." is worth adding to your answer below. This is a revelation. It's creepy that printing the address gives me zero though....