# Function passed to if statement

Tags: c, return, function-call

I have a little confusion about this statement.

```
if( Ql_StrPrefixMatch(strURC, urcHead) )
    {
        callback_NTPCMD((char*)strURC);
    }
```

The source code of **Ql_StrPrefixMatch** is:

```
    s32 Ql_StrPrefixMatch(const char* str, const char *prefix)
{
    for ( ; *str != '\0' && *prefix != '\0' ; str++, prefix++)
    {

        if (*str != *prefix) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return *prefix == '\0';
}
```

How is the if-statement evaluated to **True** or **False** based on the returns of **Ql_StrPrefixMatch** function, because it either returns 0 or *prefix == '\0'?
Does return of 0 mean **False**?
Please help me to explain this point.
Thank you in advance

Comment: In C, all non-zero values are "true", and zero is "false". That means `if( Ql_StrPrefixMatch(strURC, urcHead) )` is equivalent to `if( Ql_StrPrefixMatch(strURC, urcHead) != 0 )`. This should have been taught by any decent book, tutorial or class.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes I knew about Ql_StrPrefixMatch(strURC, urcHead) != 0 but confused about the above case.

Comment: Also note that the function `Ql_StrPrefixMatch` either returns `0` which will be considered "false", or return the result of `*prefix == '\0'` which in itself is a boolean result which will be converted to either the integer `1` (if the condition is true) or the integer `0` (if the result if false).

Comment: Now its clear. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> *....because it either returns 0 or '\0'?*

No, the second return statement uses a **comparison** operator, not an assignment. That returns either `0` or `1`. That return value is used to evaluate the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

s32 is a signed integer. The function returns eigther 0 or 1. C then interprets this as a bool.

Why does the function return 1?
 `*prefix == '\0'` gives a bool, which then is converted to s32.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed, you are current. 0 in c means false, and also, on the other hand, NULL or '\0' also evaluates to false. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459743/is-null-always-false) answer for your query. So as you can guess, if(0) and if('\0') will be evaluated to the false branch of the if statement. And also, additional information: Anything non-zero value will be evaluated as true.